# Netezza SQL query searching a concatenated value

Tags: sql, netezza, aginity

I am using Aginity workbench to query a netezza database and trying to create simple query.  Basically, within a table there are two columns that I want to combine to create an ID (they do make up two parts of actual unique IDs).  Within the query I want to search unique IDs e.g. the IDRef value. So in the below example, I want to return all rows within the table where column X equals 282 and Z equals 55. The below code isnt returning anything.

```
SELECT T_ROUTE || CSC as IDRef, *
FROM HUB_DATABASE 
WHERE POSTCODE like 'A%'
AND CURRENT_RECORD_FLAG = '1'
AND IDRef = 28255
LIMIT 100 
;
```

So the below code works ok in the same way, but just trying to use a smarter method of doing this and of course furthering my sql knowledge.

```
SELECT * FROM HUB_DATABASE
WHERE T_ROUTE = '282'
AND CSC = '55'
AND POSTCODE like 'A%'
AND CURRENT_RECORD_FLAG = 1
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery.  You cannot refer to a column alias in the same level where it is defined:

```
SELECT hb.*
FROM (SELECT T_ROUTE || CSC as IDRef, hd.*
      FROM HUB_DATABASE hd
      WHERE POSTCODE like 'A%' AND
            CURRENT_RECORD_FLAG = '1'
     ) hb
WHERE IDRef = 28255
LIMIT 100 ;
```

You will get an error if `IDRef` is already defined in `HUB_DATABASE`.  If so, you need to use a different name or remove that column from the subquery.